# Closing dialog from within ViewModel in CaliburnMicro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Suppose we have VM like this:

```
class ViewModel : Screen 
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    if(some condition)
    {
      TryClose();
    }
  }
}
```

and then in  some other class i show it using WindowManager

```
_windowManager.ShowDialog(new ViewModel());
```

but TryClose is not working here. So here comes the question: how to cancel dialog in constructor of ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor is a bad place to cancel a dialog. You could override OnViewLoaded and do your work there. There are a number of overrides you could use that happen before the dialog is actually shown.